# Prestashop HelperFrom/List - messy layout

Tags: forms, list, prestashop, helper

I'm new to prestashop and I worked the whole day on creating a back office interface that allows the user to write, edit, and delete articles. It is sort of a blog. I used Prestashop's Helpers (Form and List) and everything works great. I also added a new tab in the back office to access this tool.

The problem is that the layout is messy and doesn't look like the other forms and listing pages. The layout is really not sexy. Maybe I should look at some css file, or add any function in my controller ? You'll find the source code of the latter here (I can't insert images, not enough reputation --'):

```html
<?php
  
class Article extends ObjectModel
{
     /** @var string Name */
    public $id_article;
    public $titre;
    public $contenu;
    public $url_photo;
  
    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'article',
        'primary' => 'id_article',
        'fields' => array(
            'titre' => array(
                'type' => self::TYPE_STRING,
                'validate' => 'isGenericName',
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'lg'
            ),
            'contenu' => array(
                'type' => self::TYPE_STRING,
                'validate' => 'isGenericName',
                'required' => true
            ),
            'url_photo' => array(
                'type' => self::TYPE_STRING,
                'validate' => 'isGenericName',
                'required' => false,
            ),
            
        ),
    );
}

class AdminBlogController extends AdminController{
    
    public function initContent(){
        parent::initContent();
    }
    
    public function __construct(){
        
         $this->table = 'article';
         $this->className = 'Article';
  
         $this->lang = false;
  
        // Building the list of records stored within the "article" table
        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_article' => array(
                'title' => 'ID',
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 25
            ),
            'titre' => array(
                'title' => 'Titre',
                'width' => 'auto'
            ),
            'contenu' => array(
                'title' => 'Contenu',
                'width' => 'auto'
            )
        );
  
        // This adds a multiple deletion button
        $this->bulk_actions = array(
            'delete' => array(
                'text' => $this->l('Delete selected'),
                'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?')
            )
        );
  
        parent::__construct();
    }
  
    // This method generates the list of results
    public function renderList(){
        
        // Adds an Edit button for each result
        $this->addRowAction('edit');
  
        // Adds a Delete button for each result
        $this->addRowAction('delete');
  
        return parent::renderList();
    }
  
    // This method generates the Add/Edit form
    public function renderForm(){
        
        // Building the Add/Edit form
        $this->fields_form = array(
            'tinymce' => true,
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => 'Article'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Titre',
                    'name' => 'titre',
                    'class' => 'lg',
                    'required' => true,
                    //'desc' => 'Nom de l\'article',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'label' => 'Contenu',
                    'name' => 'contenu',
                    'class' => 'lg',
                    'required' => true,
                    'autoload_rte' => true,
                    //'desc' => 'Contenu de l\'article',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'label' => 'Photo',
                    'name' => 'url_photo',
                    'class' => 'lg',
                    'required' => true,
                    //'desc' => 'Contenu de l\'article',
                )
                
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                'class' => 'button'
            )
        );
  
        return parent::renderForm();
    }
    
}

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try setting `$this->bootstrap = true`; You can add a link to your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to set $this->bootstrap = true